# Setting context property for multiple qml files

Tags: qt, qml

I have a main.qml and inside that i have two banners(titlebanner and bottombanner) as shown in below.

```
Window {
    id: main
    visible: true

    Image {
        source: "qrc:/banner.png"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    TitleBanner {
        x:0
        y:10
    }

    BottomBanner {
        x:0
        y:420
    }
}
```

In TitleBanner.qml, i have below code

```
Item {
    Rectangle {
        id : id_title_banner

        property real value : titlebanner.title

        Image {
            source: "qrc:/banner_title.png";
        }

        //todo:: some animation stuffs on 'value' later
    }
}
```

In BottomBanner.qml, i have below code

```
Item {
    Rectangle {
        id : id_bottom_banner

        property real value : bottombanner.title

        Image {
            source: "qrc:/banner_bottom.png";
        }

        //todo:: some animation stuffs on 'value' later
    }
}
```

In C++ side, I am keeping two separate objects(for later flexibility) for both title banner and bottom banner. I set the root context property to expose the title banner objects from C++ to qml as below

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

   //create title banner object
   CTitleBanner *objTitleBanner = new CTitleBanner();

   //create bottom banner object
   CBottomBanner *objBottomBanner = new CBottomBanner();

   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
   engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("titlebanner", objTitleBanner);

   engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

   return app.exec();
```

}

My question is, how can we set context property for both titlebanner and bottombanner qml files separately instead of setting it to root context ? My concern is at later point if more banner comes, I set it to rootContext. Is it a proper way of doing ? How can we create seperate context for each banner ?

Comment: "it replaces above context property." Does it? I don't want to try it. If so. why don't you create a `QObject contextData` which has two properties:  `titlebanner` and `bottombanner` which you set to be (by coincidence maybe?) your two original banner objects. However I think the answer to my initial question should be "no".

Comment: @derM, sorry there was a correction in my question, I have edited the same. Yes. your point is correct it won't replace the previous context i tried the same. Please see my edited question.

Comment: I don't get your new question. How many banners will there be? And what impact will C++ have on this? You should strive to keep your C++ part to be as immutable as possible since QML is more flexible. Create a *stable* data model in C++, do the magic of visual representation in QML only. You might create some kind of content model in C++ if e.g. database access might be necessary. The C++ part should *not know what is in the view*.

Comment: @derM, In my above example I am setting the contextProperty for root context. So I can access the banner object from all my qml files. For example, In BottomBanner.qml file I can access 'objTitleBanner' also. I am thinking is this is a preferred way of doing ?. Later point, I am planning to add more banners (say around 20 banners ). So finally we can access all banner object from any qml file.  I don't know is this is an overhead for qt. is this so ?  So I am thinking can we set a context specific to a qml file. For example from TitleBanner.qml I can only have access to 'objTitleBanner'.

Comment: Setting context properties is really only setting properties to the very root of your QML object tree. This means, QML will follow the regular name resolution algorithm (looking in the current scope, looking in the files root scope, looking in the root scope of the file that instantiates that file e.t.c until it reaches the root context - or fails). Within one scope, the lookup should be fast since it is (afaik) implemented as a map of some sort. Having 20 context properties is less a problem, than trying to access it from deeply nested objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption:

> it replaces above context property.

is wrong:

```
// in main.cpp
QObject* obj1 = new QObject();
QObject* obj2 = new QObject();

engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("obj1", obj1);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("obj2", obj2);

qDebug() << "obj1" << obj1 << engine.rootContext()->contextProperty("obj1").value<QObject*>();
qDebug() << "obj2" << obj2 << engine.rootContext()->contextProperty("obj2").value<QObject*>();
```

---

```
// in main.qml
Component.onCompleted: console.log(obj1, obj2)
```

---

```
// output:
obj1 QObject(0x22d8c768) QObject(0x22d8c768)
obj2 QObject(0x22d8c778) QObject(0x22d8c778)
qml: QObject(0x22d8c768) QObject(0x22d8c778)
```

Both objects are there, with the right identifier.

---

*Personally* I don't like `contextProperties` since they are easily to be shadowed e.t.c. - I rather register my CPP models as singletons so I can import them at the places where I really want to have access to them. Though there are downsides of those singletons. (e.g. `qmlscene` will fail to import them)

Comment: you mean registering your model with qmlRegisterType and use setProperty from your model to set qml property ? I am also planning to replace the context property with this solution. In my case, I prefer to call my custom class as controller and registering this with qmlRegisterType and set the properties right from my custom controller class. I have another model class which associated to controller class.

Comment: No. I mean registering it with `qmlRegisterSingleton`, if the nature of the object is indeed that of a singleton [in one process]. If it is not, I'd register it as an instantiable type (`qmlRegisterType`) but then I'd also create the instance in QML (e.g. `MySubViewSpecificNonSingletonModel { }`) - the disadvantage of those methods is, that it is harder to mock them for tests, e.g. with `qmlscene`.

Comment: However using `setProperty` from C++ means, your C++ part needs a profound knowledge of your QML structure, which you will like to avoid, since you'll lose flexibility. Changing the view would mean changing the model, too. *Using* `setContextProperty` means you need to stick to a naming convention to avoid shadowing of the names. This might be problematic with 3rd-party code or coworkers.

Comment: "However using setProperty from C++ means, your C++ part needs a profound knowledge of your QML structure", Yes. I agree. But as I understand this would give more decoupling between C++ and Qt. 
I was referring the link http://www.zhieng.com/exposing-qml-object-pointer-to-cc/.  Which solution you suggest which provides more decoupling logic between Qt and C++ ?

Comment: So what he does, is instantiating an Object in QML. He has bad style with the `Component.onCompleted{ ... }` thing. He should have exposed a property, to which you can bind that object, but internally it will call the `setMyObject` - so... well. The rest is ok. Somewhat similar to what is done in `QtQuick.Controls 2.x`: You define the behavior stuff of the controls in C++, pass the visual representation via `contentItem etc.` properties to the C++ side. But most parts are done by providing properties to QML to which the designer might choose to bind to - not actively overridden in the Items.

Comment: "He should have exposed a property, to which you can bind that object" Can you please give a code snippet how to do this ?

Comment: You add below `Q_OBJECT` a line `Q_PROPERTY(<type> <name> READ <getterName> WRITE <setterName> NOTIFY <changedSignalName>)`. You implement the setter in a way that it will `emit <changeSignalName>()` when a new object is assigned that is not the same as before, and you are good. There are many resources on creating properties in QObjects for exposing them to QML. If you need more guidance, open a new question please.